# How to redirect the user to the error page from an Advice if a parameter is empty/null?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj

I'd like to redirect the user to an error page from within an Advice without having to throw an exception if a param is not specified. Is that possible? If so, how can I do it?

I'm currently throwing an exception but I feel it's overkill and the log it leaves is too much:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ParamTracker{

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("ParamTrackerLogger");

    @Before("execution(* com.controller.MainController.*(..)) && !execution(* com.controller.MainController.doNotUseThis(..))")
    public void trackParam(JoinPoint point) throws Exception {
        String methodName = point.getSignature().getName();
        String param = point.getArgs()[0].toString();
        if(param.isEmpty()) {
            logger.error("Param is empty");
            throw new Exception("Please specify param");
        } else {
            logger.info(param + ". " + methodName);
        }
    } 

}
```

Having the user redirected to an error page and a simple *Param not specified. Redirecting to error page ...* on the log would be ideal. Also, it doesn't have to be a @Before, as long as it works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use `@Before`, the only way to stop the original method from being executed is to throw an exception. If you use `@Around` instead, you can freely decide whether calling the intercepted method or not via `joinpoint.proceed()`. If you don't proceed, you can return another result instead, some response your controller would return in order to make the control flow end up at an error page. But OTOH throwing exceptions is maybe the standard way of going to an error page and you just need to adjust your log filtering. If my comment helps, let me know and I turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think one possible solution might be something like this:

1. You can write a custom exception for when a param is invalid. eg `ParamIsEmptyException`.
2. When param is empty, throw above exception instead of normal exception.
3. In your central exception handler(if you don't have it, you can simply make it), check the exception type, if the exception has `ParamIsEmptyException` type, you can use `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect` method for redirecting user to any url.